# Joda Time - Get all weeks of a year

Tags: java, jodatime, date-arithmetic

is there a way to get all weeks of a year plus start and ending days of every week ?
(With [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/))

something like this (2012) :

week : 21
start: 21.05.2012
ending : 27.05.12

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); 
Period weekPeriod = new Period().withWeeks(1);
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
Interval i = new Interval(startDate, weekPeriod );
while(i.getEnd().isBefore( endDate)) {
    System.out.println( "week : " + i.getStart().getWeekOfWeekyear()
            + " start: " + df.format( i.getStart().toDate() )
            + " ending: " + df.format( i.getEnd().minusMillis(1).toDate()));
    i = new Interval(i.getStart().plus(weekPeriod), weekPeriod);
}
```

Note that the week numbers start at 52 and then go from 1 - 51, since Jan 1 isn't on a Sunday.

If instead you want to see the dates of each Monday-Sunday week:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); 
Period weekPeriod = new Period().withWeeks(1);
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
while(startDate.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.MONDAY) {
    startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
}

DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Interval i = new Interval(startDate, weekPeriod);
while(i.getStart().isBefore(endDate)) {
    System.out.println("week : " + i.getStart().getWeekOfWeekyear()
            + " start: " + df.format(i.getStart().toDate())
            + " ending: " + df.format(i.getEnd().minusMillis(1).toDate()));
    i = new Interval(i.getStart().plus(weekPeriod), weekPeriod);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Joda-Time is in maintenance mode

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## Define ‘week’

You can define a week in different ways.

I will assume you mean the standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Week number 1 has the first Thursday of the year, starts on a Monday, and a week-based year has either 52 or 53 weeks. A few days at the end or beginning of the calendar year may land in the other week-based year.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the [java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) classes, and their extension found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

From *ThreeTen-Extra*, use the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek start = YearWeek.of( 2017 , 1 ) ;  // First week of the week-based year 2017.
```

Get the number of weeks in this week-based year, 52 or 53.

```
int weeks = start.lengthOfYear() ;
```

…or…

```
int weeks = ( start.is53WeekYear() ) ? 53 : 52 ;
```

Loop for each week of the year. For each `YearWeek`, ask it to produce a `LocalDate` for the beginning and ending of that week.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>( weeks ) ;
YearWeek yw = start ;
for( int i = 1 , i <] weeks , i ++ ) {
    String message = "Week: " + yw + " | start: " + yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) + " | stop: " + yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
    results.add( message ) ;
    // Prepare for next loop.
    yw = yw.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Never used Joda Time.
I would do something like this:

1. Create a class that has the weeknumber and two DateTimes (start, end)
2. Create a List of this class
3. Iterate over the year (week per week) and save the current week in the list

That's the way I would do this with the standard java calendar api. Probably Joda Time is a little bit easier, I don't know.

Comment: I'd probably use a database table rather than a class, but you have the right idea.